# Scripting PAW client to use test input data

Tags: paw-app

Is it possible to script PAW to execute a bunch of requests using input data from a file, like one can with SoapUI?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. It's something that we should be adding in the future as we really would like to have this feature too :)